# Distinguish between sharepoint site collection and a site in SharePoint Online (2013) using Rest API

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I would like to know if there is a way to know the difference between an SPSite and and SPWeb using the REST API.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can check using java script as shown below.

If **_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl == _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl** is **true** then it is site collection root site, and if it is **false** then it is not root site for site collection.

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate way is only by knowing the complete url. if the path of the web has sites or teams in it then it would be a site collection url otherwise it will a site.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain more on how you are trying to use this ?

If you want to know this using JavaScript, you can avoid the REST call by using the _spPageContextInfo object

The webServerRelativeUrl and siteServerRelativeUrl properties will have the same values in the root site of the site collection.

Refer [this](http://sympmarc.com/2013/03/26/using-_sppagecontextinfo-to-determine-the-current-sharepoint-context-in-script/)